# Using env variables in sql injection inside Liquibase xml

Tags: liquibase

Does someone have the right example how to use env variables in sql injection inside liquibase xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <changeSet id="customer-change-287" author="vkvsuser">
        <comment>Grant permissions to secret user</comment>
        <sql>
            GRANT SELECT ON TABLE email_audit TO ${app_db_user};
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            <sql>
                REVOKE SELECT ON TABLE email_audit FROM ${app_db_user};
            </sql>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

If I use like that I see

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL GRANT SELECT ON TABLE email_audit TO ${app_db_user}: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right. Here's the documentation on Liquibase property substitution: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html

Liquibase will leave the original `${property}` text if it does not find a matching property. You could check to make sure that the case matches, like having an environment variable named `APP_DB_USER` but referencing it as `app_db_user`. You may want to doublecheck what your OS environment is actually storing.

Finally, it could be related to this issue in Liquibase 4.21.1: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/4129

Does this only happen with version 4.21.1? Does it work if you use an older version of Liquibase, like 4.19?

Answer (score 0):

We use Liquibase with old maven plugin(3.1.x). When we updated the plugin version the problem was solved.

There were no other options to solve the problem

You must use the version 3.10.3+